# Error evaluating expression: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a Question domain model designed as follows

```
class Question {

    List<Choice> choiceCollection;

    static hasMany = [choiceCollection:Choice]
    static mappping = {
        choiceCollection(joinTable:false)
    }

}
```

To fulfill my needs, /grails-app/views/question/create.gsp has been customized as you can see below

**create.gsp**

```
<g:each var="i" in="${(0..4)}">
    <div class="fieldcontain  required">
    <label for="description">
            Option ${i + 1}.
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:textArea name="choiceCollection[${i}].description" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="2000" value="${questionInstance?.choiceCollection[i]?.description}"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

When i try to access create view, **i get the following error**

```
Error evaluating expression [questionInstance?.choiceCollection[i]?.description]: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
```

Question: What should i do to run my application ?

Grails version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of accessing by [] use getAt, then the ? Operator will work:

```
choiceCollection?.getAt(1)?.description
```

Comment: Nice one (+1). Just for curiosity: why getAt method whether List API does not define one ???

Comment: Thx. Regarding your question:There is one in the `java.util.List` of groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

Comment: Can I just use get instead of getAt?

Comment: Unfortunately not always, but possibly in this specific case

Answer (score 9):

I observed this error when attempting to run grails (2.2.4) using Java 8. The cause was not immediately obvious. It's buried somewhere grails.util.BuildSettings.groovy

When I reverted to java 1.7, the message went away.

Answer (score 0):

try to iterate only over the existing choices:

```
<g:each status="i" var="choice" in="${questionInstance.choiceCollection}">
    <div class="fieldcontain  required">
        <label for="description">
            Option ${i + 1}.
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:textArea name="choiceCollection[${i}].description" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="2000" value="${choice.description}"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

this should do the trick...